# can't start .net winapp at os start

Tags: c#, .net, windows, startup

I am developing one C#.NET winnapp, in which I require to start my app at Windows OS start. I found the code for doing it, by making my app's entry inside registry.

```
string runKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey);
if (startupKey.GetValue("my_app") == null)
{
    startupKey.Close();
    startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
    startupKey.SetValue("my_app", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
    startupKey.Close();
}
```

from the above code, I succeeded in getting entry of my app into registry, but still I am not able to see my app starting at windows start, i.e. it is not started at OS start.

Comment: That would run after a user logon, is that what you want?

Comment: If you want something that runs when the OS starts and is independant of any users logged in, it sound like you should write a [service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can always put your executable in the Windows Startup directory.  To find the directory, open your Start Menu > All Programs and right-click Startup.  Here you have the option to Explore (current user) or Explore All Users.  Anything in this directory will run when the applicable user logs into Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much..for your answer..but how can i achive that through c# code.and that too system and os independent..